# How to verify VFPv4 feature in ARM toolchain

Tags: arm, cortex-a

I have a pre-compiled ARM tool chain for a Cortex A15. I want to check whether it generate correct VFPv4 instructions. Any body have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

We can look it up in [gcc release log](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) which states

```
...
GCC now supports VFPv4-based FPUs and FPUs with single-precision-only VFP.
...
```

We can also verify it manually. According to ARM Architecture manual VFPv4 at least added `Vector Fused Multiply Accumulate / Subtract`.

```
void test_vfp4() {
    asm("VFMA.F32 q1, q2, q3");
}
```

Compiling this with `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` switch (otherwise my tool chain says `Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode 'vfma.f32 q1,q2,q3'`)

```
gcc -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -O2 -marm -c vfpv4.c
```

and dumping the binary for with

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -S vfpv4.o
```

should list below

```
00000000 <test_vfp4>:
   0:   f2042c56    vfma.f32    q1, q2, q3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

However I don't know how you can use this at C level since I couldn't find any [intrinsic listed](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) for these fused instructions or think of any other way.

Comment: I would say that what you propose is sufficient to verify the compiler, since simply the gcc binary accepting -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 means that the support is in there. Whether the compiler makes any actual use of the additional instructions is a different question altogether.

Comment: The [vfp.md](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/vfp.md;hb=HEAD#l892) has descriptions as [arm.md](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/arm.md;hb=HEAD#l1585) has the `mla` integer versions.  I have seen gcc use the `mla` versions.  It is possible that the compiler will make use of the instruction.  However, it is often difficult due to mis-match between 'C' pedantic use of IEEE floats.   Ie, de-norm and other issue will often prevent the use.  I would compile with -ffast-math if you want this.  Game rendering and rocket control have different demands.

Comment: An [excellent blog post](http://community.arm.com/groups/tools/blog/2013/04/15/arm-cortex-a-processors-and-gcc-command-lines) by Richard Earnshaw on FPU types to use with Cortex CPUs.  Use `-Ofast` or `-O3` and `-ffast-math`.